# Didn't get the records from mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have mysql installed on my PC.

I have a table `users`, in which a field is `pointsRedeemed`. When I see records using mysql workbench using query `select * from users`, and see the results, then it shows records.

In those records, I can clearly see the `pointsRedeemed` is displaying `null`.

But when I do the query like this `select * from users where pointsRedeemed=null`, then it displays me no results. I want those records in which `pointsRedeemed=null`. How to get those records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't compare columns to `NULL` values using the equals (`=`) operator.  Instead, you need to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.  The following query should yield the results you were expecting:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE pointsRedeemed IS NULL
```

For a deeper explanation, `NULL` represents an unknown value in a relational database.  Hence, the expression `pointsRedeemed = NULL` is semantically saying is `pointsRedeemed` equal to something which is unknown?  The result of this comparison is also unknown, and will never return either true or false.

Comment: ahh. thanks a lot. I was really frustrated from a long time. You made my day

Comment: Happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE pointsRedeemed IS NULL
```